# How to generate a cumulative variable for observations that fall into the highest quartile

Tags: stata

I have 4 variables

- Height
- Weight
- Length of the arms
- Length of the legs

I would like to create a variable (`new_var`) that is a summary number equal to the number of times that my observations fall into the highest quartile of each variable.

For example if you score in the highest quartile for one (and only one) of the variables above, your value in `new_var` will be one. If you score in the highest quartile in 2 variables (I doesn’t matter if the second & the fifth are the first & the second) you score will be 2 in `new_var` and so on. There are several possible combinations.

The idea is that the number of variables for which the participant’s scores fall into the highest quartile are added together to create a summary number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to know is whether values are above the upper quartile or not, you can use `summarize` directly. Watch out for missing values on any variable.

```
sysuse auto, clear 

gen score = 0 

quietly foreach v in trunk displacement length weight { 
    su `v', detail 
    noisily di "`v'{col 20}" r(p75)
    replace score = cond(missing(`v'), ., score + (`v' > r(p75))) 
} 

tab score
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create all-zero variable named score and add 1 to it every time an observation lies in the top quartile for a variable:

```
sysuse auto, clear
gen score = 0
foreach var of varlist price mpg weight headroom {
    xtile q = `var', nq(4)
    replace score = score + cond(q==4,1,0)
    drop q
} 
tab score
```